# Magento - Move cart dropdown plugin to top.links. Reference name="top.Links" not changing location

Tags: xml, magento, themes

A cart dropdown plug-in I'm using has the following XML and I'm having trouble moving it to top links.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"  ifconfig="cartdrop/general/enabled"><stylesheet>css/cartdrop.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addJs"  ifconfig="cartdrop/general/enabled"><script>lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"  ifconfig="cartdrop/general/enabled"><script>lib/cartdrop.js</script></action>
        </reference>

     <reference name="top.container">
            <!--<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="cartdrop/general/enabled"><template>cartdrop/template/header.phtml</template></action>-->

<block type="core/template" name="cartheader_sidebar" template="cartdrop/cartheader.phtml">         
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions"/>
    </block>
</block>

        </reference>
    </default> 
</layout>
```

I've tried changing the reference name to `reference name="topLinks"` and `reference name="top.Links"`

I've also tried copying the block and pasting it in local.xml under `<reference name="top.links">`  and putting it in page.xml but to no avail.

---

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `<reference name="top.links">` as the attribute said -> reference NAME

The problem why it is not displayed is:
- Look at the definition of `top.links` -> `<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>`
- Then go to `Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php`

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    ...

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('page/template/links.phtml');
    }

    ...
}
```

Now we know that `top.links` extend from `core/template`.
For those blocks which extend from `core/template` require a template (simple isn't it),
it will display everything inside the template (in your case, the template is `page/template/links.phtml`)

For a template, to be able to render its child, it should explicitly call `getChildHtml`

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>` -> will render all child under it

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cartheader_sidebar'); ?>` -> will render child with alias/name `cartheader_sidebar`

It means if you want `cartheader_sidebar` to be displayed in `top.links`, you need to put `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cartheader_sidebar'); ?>` in `page/template/links.phtml`

PS: I don't check your layout, I assume it is already correct

Answer (score 0):

Layout XML:

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="cart-link" template="Magento_Theme::cart_link.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">#/</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

And:

```
    <move element="minicart" destination="cart-link" />
```

cart_link.phtml:

```
 <li>My Cart
 <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart');?>
 </li>
```